# How can i use two GMSMapViews in single project in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps, viewcontroller, gmsmapview

In my project i am using `GMSMapView` in two `ViewControllers`. My project contain two types of logins . So i created two `StoryBoards`. two logins contains two types of google maps. I taken `UIView` for `GMSMapView`. If i try to use two `Maps`.My app giving following crash.Here my question is how  can i use two `GMSMapViews` in single project?. please give me suggestions to fix this issue.

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Following code is my Outlet connection for `GMSMapView`.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Comment: What is reason for crash? can you add that in question?

Comment: @  Dharmesh Kheni. i am not getting what was the reason exactly i guess by using two GMSMapView in single Project. Earlier i was using only one that time its not crashing when ever i try to use two maps i am facing this error.  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you share demo projecT?

Comment: i cant share i am using in my live project.

Comment: @kishan  using two GMSMapView in single Project can never be a reason for a crash.Some more proper info will be required to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How wonder it is i don't know now its working with out showing any error. i did   Alt+Shift+command+K and quit Xcode restart it and run again its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are created `mapview`

```
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, frame.size.width-20, 100))
```

in `viewDidLoad` instead of

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Comment: nope i taken @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!. i set constraints in storyboard only